# Problem with Updating unique together constraint Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Tried to updating unqiue_together constraint using Django-ORM

While Migrating getting following error :

```
File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
main()
File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/Gateway-26Oct/gateway/gateway/manage.py", line 24, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 536, in database_forwards
getattr(new_model._meta, self.option_name, set()),
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 365, in alter_unique_together
self._delete_composed_index(model, fields, {'unique': True}, self.sql_delete_unique)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 88, in _delete_composed_index
return super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self)._delete_composed_index(model, fields, *args)
File "/Users/arpitkoolwal/DEV/cld/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 394, in _delete_composed_index
", ".join(columns), ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for test(a, b)
```

Django : 1.11.15

Error Ticket : [Django-Offical](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28697#comment:2)

Can anyone tell me, How can we modify existing unique constraint using Django-ORM ?

EDIT :

Model -

```
class test(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    d = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
     unique_together = ('a', 'b')
```

Migration Code :

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('demo', '0230_auto_20181106_1243'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
        name='test',
        unique_together=set([a,b]),
    ),
]
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: @bak2trak Can you check now  ?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it, it's working fine for me which db are you using. I checked it after creating normal table then adding this constraint. (using default sqlite3)

Comment: now once you added the constraint try removing this. The issue, I am facing with mysql 5.7. Dont know about sqlite

Comment: Still working fine. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623515/received-valueerror-found-wrong-number-0-of-constraints-for-during-djan#41623516

Comment: Yes i have seen but didnt work for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183493/discussion-between-arpit-and-bak2trak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved the problem:

1. `python -m pdb manage.py migrate`
2. type `up` to go upper frame. It will go to

   ./python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py(363)alter_unique_together()
   -> self._delete_composed_index(model, fields, {'unique': True}, self.sql_delete_unique)
3. type `a` to show variables

Notice

```
old_unique_together = {('a', 'b')}
new_unique_together = {('a', 'b', 'c')}
```

that the `old_unique_together` does not exist, according to pg `\d tablename`

4. Go to old migration files and find old `migrations.AlterUniqueTogether`, comment them, then run the migration again.
5. ???
6. profit.

Comment: Thanks! Did the same

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this error, took quite sometime to figure out. I borrowed from the accepted answer and commented out the most recent `AlterUniqueTogether` in the relevant migration file. Unsure if this will cause long term instability, but it allowed the migration to work.

Answer (score 0):

One situation I know where that problem occurs is when you upgraded an existing Django application and you started the migration history from scratch.
The initial migration script may initialize the constraint in an order different from the one in the database.
So when you remove (or modify) the unique_together constraint it doesn't match.

The model used to be

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "My Model"
        unique_together = (('name', 'label'),)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

It has been changed to

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "My Model"
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The database shows :

```
UNIQUE KEY `app_mymodel_name_77dd4fb8f340a397_uniq`       (`label`, `name`)
```

In the initial migration script **0001_initial.py**

```
migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(                                         
    name='mymodel',                                                   
    unique_together=set([('name', 'label', )]),               
),
```

In the new migration script **0007_auto_20220916_1454.py**

```
migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(                                         
    name='mymodel',                                                   
    unique_together=set([]),               
),
```

Solution :
Change the order of the arguments of the **migrations.AlterUniqueTogether** call in the initialization migration script (**0001_initial.py**)

```
migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(                                         
    name='mymodel',                                                   
    unique_together=set([('label', 'name', )]),               
),
```

And launch the migration again.